# How can you get a xaml element using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a xaml page `samplePage.xaml` and its corresponding .cs file `samplePage.xaml.cs`. In this page there is a textBox `textBox1`.
Now I create an instance of the page:

```
PhoneApp1.samplePage s = new PhoneApp1.samplePage();
```

and after that, I would like to set the value in the text box by calling:

```
s.textBox1.Text = "whatever"
```

but it turns out there is an error message saying

> 'PhoneApp1.samplePage' does not contain a definition for 'textBox1'
>   and no extension method 'textBox1' accepting a first argument of type
>   PhoneApp1.samplePage' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I would like to know how to get the xaml element using C# code?

Comment: That's really odd, I wrote a short test and accessing named xaml elements from C# works perfectly here. Can you post more code, e.g. the xaml of your TextBox and the location of your C# calls?

Comment: I don't think this method will work with NavigationService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You textbox is probably private or protected. Add a wrapper in your page to expose the textbox, something like :

```
public TextBox TextBox1
{
    get
    {
        return this.textBox1;
    }
}
```

(mind the case)

Then just use the property from anywhere you want: `s.TextBox1.Text = "whatever";`

Answer (score 0):

Good question, you'll need to use XamlReader.Load to load your page/control at runtime, then you'll be able to access the controls within it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189076(v=vs.95).aspx#using_xamlreaderload

http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/10/09/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-60-how-to-load-a-control-straight-from-xaml.aspx

Comment: actually i solved it in another way while this is a good solution indeed. Thanks!